# ios5 backward compatibility

Tags: ios, ios5

A quick curiosity.
If I develop an application with ios 5(e.g core audio kAudioUnitSubType_AudioFilePlayer) components and set the deployment target to ios 4 will the ios 5 components work on an ios 4 device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since nobody can travel back in time, you cannot use iOS 5 features on iOS 4.

However, you can write an app that runs fine on iOS 4 and uses iOS 5 features if available. For example, you can ask a class whether it implements a method using `respondsToSelector:`, and if so, you can call it.

With `kAudioUnitSubType_AudioFilePlayer`, you can simply try to initialize the audio unit with `AUGraphNewNode` but on iOS 4 you will get an error (but not a crash).

Answer (score 1):

An application running on iOS 4.x only has access to the APIs available in the 4.x frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend for new apps, as of today... that you develop for iOS 5 using iOS 5 features. After you are done, do some regression testing on iOS 4.  Whatever is broken, re-write, or allow the app to do something different at runtime (you can check if an object would respond to a method before calling it ;)).  This will allow you to use all the sweet iOS 5 stuff with the least 'settling'.  My team created some of the new features in iOS 5 IN iOS 4 (dealing the the navigation controller) so that the code would require very little change.

Comment: Storyboards are a problem, if you use them ios5, and then try to convert to ios4.